# Add checkbox in Excel with Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, checkbox

I'm trying to add form control checkboxes in Excel with Powershell. I managed to do it using the following code

```
$CheckBoxes = $ExcelWorkSheet.CheckBoxes()
$checkbox = $CheckBoxes.Add(Left,Top,Width,Height).Value = 1
#Left,Top,Width,Height are numbers
```

My problem is that I get caption for the checkbox next to it.
When I do

```
$checkbox = $CheckBoxes.Add(Left,Top,Width,Height).Caption = ""
```

I get no caption but the checkbox is not checked and I need it checked.

I tried

```
$checkbox = $CheckBoxes.Add(Left,Top,Width,Height).Caption("").Value(1)

$checkbox1 = $CheckBoxes.Add(500,500,2,5)
$checkbox1 = $CheckBoxes.Caption = ""
$checkbox1 = $CheckBoxes.Value = 1
```

With no luck. Even when setting the width to 0 I still see "chec" next to it

My question is. How can I add the checkbox with no caption and checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$Checkbox` variable is not a real checkbox object, it's a [int] object as you set his value with the output of `$checkbox.Add[...].value = 1'`

You need to change This:

```
$checkbox = $CheckBoxes.Add(Left,Top,Width,Height).Value = 1
```

To This:

```
$checkbox = $CheckBoxes.Add(Left,Top,Width,Height)
$checkbox.Value = 1
$checkbox.Text = ""
```